# Toggle switch is overriding click event

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an android app and on one page I have a clickable TextView and also a toggle switch. For some reason, when I try to click on the TextView it triggers the toggle instead. Can anyone help with the issue?

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Activities.SettingsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_settings">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationTime"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Day Mode"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="45dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think that maybe using layout_align to parent in all directions is making the switch fill the whole line in combo with wrap_content even though that doesn't make the switch look bigger because you set a limit on the height. Try setting a limit on width or creating different constraints.

Answer (score 0):

According to your xml code, Switch is on top of Textview.

You need to set constraints to Switch to avoid the problem. Remove the alignParentTop and alignParentStart constrains for TextView and if you want Switch below the TextView. You need to add the constraintTop_toBottomOf constraint. Refer to the below code.

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Day Mode"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notificationTime"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```